# ¿Cómo cambiar una columna de un array por otro array en python?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo una matriz 4x4

```
a= ([[-54.,  25.,   0.,   0.],
     [ 25., -54.,  25.,   0.],
     [  0.,  25., -54.,  25.],
     [  0.,   0.,  25., -54.]])
```

y un vector 4x1

```
b=([[ -0.8],
    [ -1.6],
    [ -2.4],
    [-53.2]])
```

Quiero cambiar una columna de la matriz a por el vector `b`.

Esto se puede hacer facilmente con indexacion cuando el vector `b` es una lista, así:

```py
a[:,1]=b
```

Pero cuando `b` es un array, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4,)
```

Hay alguna función de Numpy con la que se pueda realizar esta tarea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que `b` es un "vector columna" (es decir, sus dimensiones son `(4, 1)` pues tiene 4 filas y 1 elemento en cada una), pero la rodaja en la que intentas meterlo mediante `a[:,1]` espera un vector normal (de dimensión 4, es decir, 1 fila con 4 elementos o lo que es lo mismo, forma `(1,4)`).

Eso es precisamente lo que significa el error *"could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4,)"*, que no ha podido meter el array de forma (4,1) en un sitio donde esperaba uno de forma (4,) que es lo mismo que decir (1,4) en este caso.

La solución es simple. Si `b` es una matriz de dimensiones (4,1), su transpuesta `b.T` tendrá dimensiones (1,4) como necesitamos. Por tanto lo siguiente funcionará:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[-54.,  25.,   0.,   0.],
     [ 25., -54.,  25.,   0.],
     [  0.,  25., -54.,  25.],
     [  0.,   0.,  25., -54.]])
b = np.array(
   [[ -0.8],
    [ -1.6],
    [ -2.4],
    [-53.2]])

# Aqui realizo la asignación que pides
a[:,1] = b.T

print(a)
```

El resultado es el esperado:

```
array([[-54. ,  -0.8,   0. ,   0. ],
       [ 25. ,  -1.6,  25. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,  -2.4, -54. ,  25. ],
       [  0. , -53.2,  25. , -54. ]])
```

Otra opción es usar `b.flatten()` para eliminar la anidación que hay dentro de la matriz-vector `b` y dejarlo como una simple secuencia de números. En este ejemplo `b.flatten()` retornará `[ -0.8,  -1.6,  -2.4, -53.2]`, que puede ser asignado también a la rodaja `a[:, 1]`.

**Ampliación**. Otra solución más consiste en modificar la sintaxis del lado izquierdo de la asignación, y poner esto:

```
a[: , 1:2] = b
```

En este caso estás asignando `b` a la "submatriz" de `a` formada por todas las columnas entre la 1 y la 2. Es una sola columna, pero el hecho de haberlo escrito como la rodaja `1:2` hace que numpy entienda ya que un vector columna como `b` es válido para esa asignación.